# ListView won't update even if I call notifyChange(uri, null); though content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter

I'm having trouble trying to get my ListView to refresh when new data gets added to the content provider.

Reading similar posts on this issue, I made sure to use `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` on my insert method and 
`c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);` on my query method (talking about the content provider class).

I implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` in my activity:

```
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(ChatWindowActivity.this,
                                DatabaseContentProvider.getConversationUri(conversationId),
                                PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        switch (loader.getId()) {
            case LOADER_ID:
                mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
                break;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

And I'm using a custom cursor adapter with `getItemViewType`,`getViewTypeCount`,`newView` and `bindView` overridden (class extends `CursorAdapter`)

And in my service I call `service.getContentResolver().insert(...,values)`, yet the activity ListView will not update unless I close and reopen the app.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this but posting here in case it helps someone in the future.

The problem was with `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);`. The content provider will notify that a change occured on the **specific** URI only.

So I had to make sure the `CursorLoader` and the insert call worked on exactly the same URI for this to work. Even a small difference like '`/contacts/1`' to '`/contacts`' would not notify the cursor to that it changed.